# Android - Firebase Level of Access

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am new to Android Development and still learning about basics and trying to get an different access I have this structure in my database I'm getting the value of status and using at as user type

[image: Database Structrure]

and I got this error

```
java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
at com.example.gab.quadrantms.LoginActivity$1$1$1.onDataChange(LoginActivity.java:116)
```

Login

```
private DatabaseReference mUserType;
mUserType = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("status");

mUserType.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS POINTING
    String status = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
     if(status.equals("Project Manager"))
     {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Home.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
     }
     else
     {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FirebaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(current_user_id);

ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

      String status = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
      if(status.equals("Project Manager"))
      {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Home.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
      }
      else
      {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
      }
  }
```

First you need to create a reference to the node `Users` then since you need to access the child `status`, and since you have a random id under the node `Users`. You have to loop inside the direct children of the dataSnapshot(which is in this case the node `Users`) and you will be able to get the value of `status`.

Comment: I usually prefer `ds.child("status").getValue(String.class)`, because it prevents unintentional type conversion, and doesn't result in an NPE when the `status` property is not present in the database.

Comment: I was able to login but it is disregarding the If and only doing the else statement

Comment: How come that the status value isn't getting the "Project Manager"?

Comment: @GabrielApostol try `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead of `addValueEventListener`

Comment: @PeterHaddad it's still the same :(

Comment: @GabrielApostol you have many `ids` with attribute under the `User` node thats why it is getting another status when looping. You need to get the value of the id

Comment: @PeterHaddad i already have the id `String current_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();`

Comment: @GabrielApostol then add it here `FirebaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(current_user_id);` and remove the for loop, `String status = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();`